# Is there a way to stop canva and textinput from overlapping in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I made a code where you can draw lines with a kivy canva and I wanted to add a Textinput. But the problem is that when I trie clicking on the Textinput, kivy wants to draw a line and it gives me an error :

```
" File "/myfolders/test.py", line 45, in on_touch_up
     touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
 KeyError: 'line' "
```

Here is my code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from time import sleep
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from math import *
isLine=False
length=0


class MyBackground(Widget):

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source='chouettes3.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.bind(size=self.update_bg)
     def update_bg(self, *args):
         self.bg.pos = self.pos
         self.bg.size = self.size


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): 
             with self.canvas:
                 self.canvas.clear()
                 d=15
                 Rectangle(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
                 touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=3)



    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        #if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): 
             touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
             points=touch.ud['line'].points
             length=sqrt(((points[0]-points[2])**2)+((points[1]-points[3])**2))
             print (length)
             with self.canvas:
                 d=15
                 Rectangle(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))



class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        f = FloatLayout()
        s = Scatter()
        b = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        parent = MyBackground()
        painter = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={'x': 100, 'center_y': 100}, size_hint=(None, None))
        textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world')
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(textinput)
        f.add_widget(parent)
        sleep(0.1)
        return f




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

I tried the self.collide_point technique, where something only works when you click on the widget in question but that just doesn't draw a line anymore.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is your use of the `Widget` class as a container for other `Widgets`. You should use a `Layout` class to contain other `Widgets`, otherwise, things like `pos_hint` have no effect. So I have modified your code to make  `MyBackground` extend `FloatLayout`. Also, using `collide_point()` is a good idea, but usually, when you override a class method, you should also call the overridden method using `super()`. With that in mind, here is your modified code, that I think will work as you intended:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from math import *
isLine=False
length=0


class MyBackground(FloatLayout):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Rectangle(source='chouettes3.jpg', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

        self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.bind(size=self.update_bg)

     def update_bg(self, *args):
         self.bg.pos = self.pos
         self.bg.size = self.size


class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             with self.canvas:
                 self.canvas.clear()
                 d=15
                 Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
                 Rectangle(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
                 touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=3)
        return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
         if 'line' not in touch.ud:
             return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)
         if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
             points=touch.ud['line'].points
             length=sqrt(((points[0]-points[2])**2)+((points[1]-points[3])**2))
             print (length)
             with self.canvas:
                 d=15
                 Rectangle(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
         return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)


class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = MyBackground()
        painter = MyPaintWidget(pos_hint={'x':0., 'center_y':0.5}, size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', pos=(0,0), size_hint=(0.1,0.1))
        parent.add_widget(painter)
        parent.add_widget(self.textinput)
        return parent


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

I have also eliminated some unused code in the `build()` method.

As the code stands, clicking in the `TextInput` will not start a new line, but you can end a line behind the `TextInput`. If you don't want that to happen, you can add a collision test in the `on_touch_up()` method to handle it as shown below:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
     if 'line' not in touch.ud:
         return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)
     ti = App.get_running_app().textinput
     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and not ti.collide_point(*touch.pos):
         touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
         points=touch.ud['line'].points
         length=sqrt(((points[0]-points[2])**2)+((points[1]-points[3])**2))
         print (length)
         with self.canvas:
             d=15
             Rectangle(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
     else:
         self.canvas.clear()
     return super(MyPaintWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't want the line to draw itself behind the Textinput. But I don't understand where I need to change something to create a collision code. There is a collide_point in both of them... I can't seem to find where you changed something to create the collision in the on_touch_down...

Comment: I added another version of the `on_touch_up()` method that checks for a collision with the `TextInput` to avoid drawing lines that end behind it.